# I'm having a problem with the Tower of Hanoi using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, testing, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to write a piece of code to create a method that prints a string with the correct steps to solve the puzzle of the Towers of Hanoi but I'm having a small problem. The output is correct but at the end, it displays an additional value of "undefined".I tried that same code with ruby and it works perfectly.

```
 hanoi_steps = (numberOfDiscs) => {
    move(numberOfDiscs, 1, 2 , 3);
}

move =  ( numberOfDiscs,start, intermediate, goal) => {
  if (numberOfDiscs <= 0) {
      return;
  }

  move(numberOfDiscs - 1, start, goal, intermediate)
  console.log(`${start}->${goal}`)
  move(numberOfDiscs - 1, intermediate, start, goal)
}



console.log(hanoi_steps(2));
```

Output:

```
1->2
1->3
2->3
undefined
```

Comment: Do you need that console.log around your initial call to your method?

Comment: Yes, in the last line you are logging the return value from a function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your valuable feedback, The console log in the last line was useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually The problem has been resolved just by removing the console.log call at the last line (Thanks to the comments)

```
 hanoi_steps = (numberOfDiscs) => {
    move(numberOfDiscs, 1, 2 , 3);
}

move =  ( numberOfDiscs,start, intermediate, goal) => {
  if (numberOfDiscs <= 0) {
      return;
  }

  move(numberOfDiscs - 1, start, goal, intermediate)
  console.log(`${start}->${goal}`)
  move(numberOfDiscs - 1, intermediate, start, goal)
}


hanoi_steps(2);
```

Output

```
1->2
1->3
2->3
```